# How to pass xml to View in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xml, asp.net-mvc

It provide xml in string from the request. After deserialized, I cant reach any value from xml with `get` method. Also in `Vehicle.cshtml`, I tried to get `DeviceId` value. It get only string name `DeviceId` to the html label. Not getting value. Whats wrong with my way? How can I get this values of xml from view?

```
DataSet.cs

using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ShippingProject.Models
{
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("DataSet", Namespace = "http://www.arvento.com/", IsNullable = false)]

    [XmlRoot("DataSet")]
    public class DataSet
    {
        [XmlElement("Device_x0020_No")]
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Latitude")]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Longitude")]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
} 

HomeController.cs

 public IActionResult Vehicle()
        {
            // Create web client.
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            // Download string.
            string value = client.DownloadString("http://ws.arvento.com//v1/report.asmx/GetVehicleStatus?Username=username&PIN1=password&PIN2=password&Language=string");

            // Write values.
            Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
            Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataSet>), new XmlRootAttribute("DataSet"));
            //  DataSet result;
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
            var rdr = new XmlTextReader(ms) { Namespaces = false };
          //  StringReader rdr = new StringReader(value);
          /*  using (TextReader rdr = new StringReader(value))
                  {
                      result = (DataSet)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                  } 
               StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(value);*/
            List<DataSet> datasetList = (List<DataSet>)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
            Console.WriteLine("--- Deserialize result ---");
            Console.WriteLine(datasetList);
            datasetList.ForEach(dl => {
                Console.WriteLine(dl.DeviceId);
                Console.WriteLine(dl.Latitude);
                Console.WriteLine(dl.Longitude);
                Console.WriteLine(dl.Address);
                Console.WriteLine();
            });
            return View();
        }

Vehicle.cshtml
@model DataSet
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceId)
```

this is my xml file:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.arvento.com/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="tblVehicleStatus">
<xs:element name="tblVehicleStatus" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="dtVehicleStatus">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Device_x0020_No" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Speed" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Building_x0020__x002F__x0020_Region" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Height" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<tblVehicleStatus xmlns="">
<dtVehicleStatus diffgr:id="dtVehicleStatus1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<Device_x0020_No>805251</Device_x0020_No>
<GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time>2020-07-10T06:00:55+03:00</GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time>
<Latitude>41.070751</Latitude>
<Longitude>29.000586</Longitude>
<Speed>0</Speed>
<Address>Cemal Sururi Sk., Gülbahar Mh., Şişli, İstanbul, Türkiye</Address>
<Building_x0020__x002F__x0020_Region/>
<Height>205</Height>
</dtVehicleStatus>
<dtVehicleStatus diffgr:id="dtVehicleStatus2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<Device_x0020_No>805252</Device_x0020_No>
<GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time>2020-07-08T13:33:24+03:00</GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time>
<Latitude>41.071037</Latitude>
<Longitude>29.00054</Longitude>
<Speed>7.86</Speed>
<Address>Şat Otopark, Çamlı Sk., Gülbahar Mh., Şişli, İstanbul, Türkiye</Address>
<Building_x0020__x002F__x0020_Region/>
<Height>151</Height>
</dtVehicleStatus>
<dtVehicleStatus diffgr:id="dtVehicleStatus3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<Device_x0020_No>805253</Device_x0020_No>
<GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time>2020-07-10T05:31:43+03:00</GMT_x0020_Date_x002F_Time>
<Latitude>41.071087</Latitude>
<Longitude>29.000429</Longitude>
<Speed>6.31</Speed>
<Address>Şat Otopark, Çamlı Sk., Gülbahar Mh., Şişli, İstanbul, Türkiye</Address>
<Building_x0020__x002F__x0020_Region/>
<Height>103</Height>
</dtVehicleStatus>
</tblVehicleStatus>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: You cannot serialize an xml that has to list at root (List<DataSet>).  The Net serializer will fail unless the root is a singleton.

Comment: I should replace all `List<DataSet>` with `DataSet` only?

Comment: I would need to see samples of the xml to give an accurate answer.  All I can say right now is the List<> will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
            ConsoleApplication8.DataSet dataset = (ConsoleApplication8.DataSet)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
 
        }
    }
    public class Diffgram
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "tblVehicleStatus", Namespace = "")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "dtVehicleStatus", Namespace = "")]
        public List<DtVehicleStatus> DtVehicleStatus { get; set; } 
    }
    public class DtVehicleStatus
    {
            [XmlElement("Device No")]
            public string DeviceId { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Latitude")]
            public double Latitude { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Longitude")]
            public double Longitude { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Address")]
            public string Address { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSet", Namespace = "http://www.arvento.com/")]
    public class DataSet
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "diffgram", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1")]
        public Diffgram Diffgram { get; set; }
    }
 

}
```

Comment: thanks for your helping. Where I will add this code in my project. Can you write this. When I added it in HomeController. Namespace make problem.

Comment: Replace your classes with my class.   Then you only have to modify two lines to match my code 1) XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataSet>), new XmlRootAttribute("DataSet")); 2) List<DataSet> datasetList = (List<DataSet>)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);

Comment: I have some syntax error with that. I uploaded my code here. Could you check that? [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7tneXm)

Comment: I would just use your old code and drop my classes in place of your code.  The namespace may be giving issues.